# grep exact match two parts of a string

Tags: grep, regular-expression

How do I use grep command to get part of string as below?

String:

```
orange:"orange", red:"apple", purple:"grape", yellow:"banana", green:"watermelon"
red:"strawberries", yellow:"lemon"
```

What I want:

```
red:"apple" yellow:"banana"
red:"strawberries" yellow:"lemon"
```

I have tried this:

```
grep -oP '(red:\"[^\"]*).*(yellow:\"[^\"]*)'
```

Comment: You can get the output `red:"apple" yellow:"banana"` by typing the command `echo 'red:"apple" yellow:"banana"'`. If you want output based on the input, specify what extraction rule you want to use. People are assuming that you want to extract the red and yellow fruits, but you haven’t said so. (Maybe you want the first and the third, or the first and the last, or every one where the color name + the fruit name add up to an even number of letters.) … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … Is the “red” fruit guaranteed to be the first one on the line? Is the “yellow” fruit guaranteed to be the last one on the line? Is there guaranteed to be exactly one between them? … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.*` in the middle is matching everything, i.e. the `purple:"grape"` part. Instead (assuming you want to stick with GNU grep), I'd match each part separately with the `(foo|bar)` "OR" construct.

```
grep -oP '(red|yellow):\"[^\"]*"'
```

N.B. I had to add the closing `"`. Also, you don't need to escape the `"`, so you can use

```
grep -oP '(red|yellow):"[^"]*"'
```

In any case, this gives you

```
red:"apple"
yellow:"banana"
```

then to join the lines with space between them,

```
grep -oP '(red|yellow):"[^"]*"' | paste -sd ' ' -
```

Honestly, I'd naturally use `sed` instead.

```
sed -n 's/.*\(red:"[^"]*"\).*\(yellow:"[^"]*"\).*/\1 \2/p'
```

Comment: I was faster, but you give the richer explanation so I'll delete mine

Comment: @Philippos Totally up to you, but I think you are definitely justified in leaving it up!

Comment: @Philippos And thank you for the edit; good point.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` does not normally extract content off lines. It `p`rints the lines that match a `r`egular `e`xpression (`g`lobally, it's named after the `g/re/p` `ed` command).

Some implementations like GNU `grep` which you seem to be using have a `-o` to do some of that as an extension however.

`pcregrep` goes even further. Its `-o` can take an optional numerical argument to output the content of a capture group as opposed to the whole matched portion of the line.

```
pcregrep -o1 -o2 --om-separator=' ' '(red:"[^"]*").*(yellow:"[^"]*")'
```

That's still limited in what it can do.

To extract information from the line and do more transformation, it's a text `s`tream `ed`itor you'd want instead as others have shown here.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed do it with `grep` as [suggested by Sparhawk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/522107/22222), or with the almost identical:

```
$  echo 'red:"apple", purple:"grape", yellow:"banana"' |      
        grep -oP '(red|yellow):".+?"' | perl -00pe 's/\n/ /'
red:"apple" yellow:"banana"
```

Personally, I'd probably do it with `perl`:

```
$ echo 'red:"apple", purple:"grape", yellow:"banana"' | 
    perl -F, -ane 'map{print if /red|yellow/}@F'
red:"apple" yellow:"banana"
```